# Terminal de VScode tiene una ruta extraña

Tags: python, vscode, terminal, pycharm, activedirectory

tengo meses programando en visual studio sin problemas. No sé que cambio en la computadora, ahora cada vez que uso la terminal al final del CWD dice "[main ≡ +1 ~1 -0 !]".

De momento creo que no me ha afectado en nada. Igual, me da curiosidad si eso pudiese llegar a ocasionar problemas.

De ser posible me gustaría desactivarlo porque me incomoda.   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ves en la consola añadido al prompt tiene que ver con un módulo de Powershell que se llama posh-git que añade un resumen del estado de git en el folder.

Para poder desactivarlo necesitas ubicar el archivo del perfil de powershell que carga la consola al arrancar, para eso puedes teclear en la consola

`code $profile.CurrentUserAllHosts`

Con eso puedes editar el archivo en VSCode y tienes que buscar la línea donde esté `Import-Module posh-git` necesitas comentar o borrar esa línea junto con las líneas de variables para la configuración del módulo que deben comenzar con `$GitPromptSettings`, `$GitTabSettings`, y `$TortoiseGitSettings`